# wordpress- new posts not appearing on blogpage

Tags: wordpress, post, blogs

I built a site for someone and now new posts are being published but not appearing on the blog role.

I can see them at their url and also when I click on the author (eg. http://robinsonhambro.com/author/master/).

But still they do not show up on the blog page (located at Karina's Column- button on top right).

Can anyone help me with what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That links to [/category/all/](http://robinsonhambro.com/category/all/), but your recent posts are uncategorised and show up at [/category/uncategorised/](http://robinsonhambro.com/category/uncategorised/).